# Is it possible to rerender an outputpanel that's in the parent page from within a component?

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I am trying to break my page into multiple components so it can be reused on several pages. The component is essentially a form and after submission, would like the parent page to rerender a certain outputpanel block. This is the code I used to use:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="reRenderNewFeedPanel" action="{!afterSaveAttachment}" reRender="NewFeedPanel, FeedListPanel" />
```

but from within the component, the reRender on "FeedListPanel" doesn't seem to work, because it's not refreshing.

Comment: UPDATE: I thought calling the reRender from the component wasn't working, but after putting in a javascript alert with counter, it looks like it is actually being reRendered. The reason I thought it wasn't working is because the data in the "FeedListPanel" wasn't refreshing with the newest data. Why is it that when I broke out the section into a component, the reRender isn't pulling the latest data?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can rerender an element on the parent from the component. The component just gets merged into the DOM of the parent.

**NOTE** What you cannot do is update values of the parent controller from the component unless you pass in those vales (i.e. sObject, record, wrapper, etc) as an attribute to the component

To illustrate:

**VF Page (Parent)**

```
<apex:page>


<script>
    var x = 0;
</script>

<c:mytestcomponent/>

<apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="parentDiv">
    <script>
        x += 1;
        alert('The value of x is now: ' + x);
    </script>
</apex:outputPanel>


</apex:page>
```

**Component**

```
<apex:component >


    <apex:form >
        <apex:commandButton value="Click Me" rerender="parentDiv"/>
    </apex:form>

</apex:component>
```

On load you get an alert of '1'. On each click of the button in the component the value of x increments due to the rerender.

If you think something else is happening then change the name of the rerender attribute to something that does not exist and you will see that you get no alert. Thus it is the rerender that is working here

Comment: Thanks Eric, but is there a way to invoke it without a commandButton? Take a look at my actionFunction code. That's where I'd like the reRender to trigger.

Comment: @slim actionfunction and command button no difference. Take my example and start adding in your actionfunction little by little verifying it works. When it breaks as you add your stuff you will know why.

Comment: UPDATE: I thought calling the reRender from the component wasn't working, but after putting in a javascript alert with counter, it looks like it is actually being reRendered. The reason I thought it wasn't working is because the data in the "FeedListPanel" wasn't refreshing with the newest data. Why is it that when I broke out the section into a component, the reRender isn't pulling the latest data?

Comment: @slim - The controller in the main page is separate from the component. If you want to modify data from the main page you need to pass it to the component via the `<apex:attribute>` if you do not do that then the main page controller data will not be updated.

Comment: Thanks @Eric. Even if the main page is told to reRender part of its own page? It's just supposed to update the FeedListPanel with the newly posted content. The component I have created was just the posting part of the page, where the user creates a new post. The FeedListPanel is supposed to refresh and have the new post. I know it's reRendering, but the new content isn't shown.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not directly. It requires some JavaScript an an extra round-trip to the server. This requires the parent's cooperation.

```
<!-- parent page -->
<apex:actionFunction name="refreshPage" reRender="NewFeedPanel, FeedListPanel" />

 <!-- component -->
 <apex:actionFunction name="reRenderNewFeedPanel" action="{!afterSafeAttachment}" onComplete="refreshPage()" />
```

Comment: see below for an example of this working. Only know this for sure because I have made heavy use of it lately to put a page on its own and in a configuration wizard page.

Comment: I tried this method and it's not working. Any idea why it wouldn't work?